# How to make my horizontal Spry menubar vertical?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver, spry

I have a horizontal menu bar at the top of this page:

I didn't code this site and I'm unfamiliar with Spry.

I need to make it vertical and on the left of the images.

How can I set spry to make the navbar vertical?

I have dreamweaver, but I can't find a horizontal or vertical setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css float property to make it vertical.

For position your nav bar to left of the image you can use position property.

**CSS:**

```
#MenuBar {
    left: 316px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 201px;
}

.MenuBar .MenuItemContainer {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

simply remove float or make it none in MenuItemContainer

Comment: Thanks. I thought I would have to change some Spry settings :P